# RGB code won't work when I don't use space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax, rgb

I use this function to check the bottom part of my table cell and then later change its color.

```
function checkBottom(colIndex) {
  var colorReport = returnColor(5,colIndex);
  for (var row = 5; row > -1; row--) {
    colorReport = returnColor(row,colIndex);
    if(colorReport==='rgb(128,128,128)'){
      return row;
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't do anything unless I change the `if` part to:
`colorReport==='rgb(128, 128, 128)'`

What's different between `rgb(a,a,a)` and `rgb(a, a, a)`?

Comment: Why should the comparison of strings ignore spaces? o.O

Comment: What's different between  "AA" and "A A" - are you saying you can't see the difference?

Comment: That's just how strings behave. If you try to compare `"marc oriley" === "marco riley"` they won't match because they're different strings (in this case different names)

Comment: Your real solution would to be not to check the colour - but instead add a `class` and check for the existence of that class.  Then if you want to change the colour in future, you can do it in the css instead of your code (and then have the issue where you forget to change it in n-1 of the n places you've randomly added it...)

Comment: @Andreas so you are sayin in system it saves like this: rgb(a, a, a)?
and for comparison I should use this style?

Comment: No. Where did I say/mention something like that? I have no idea what `returnColor()` does. Maybe that's just the way that function returns that value. Maybe its the way the browser returns that value... Don't compare colors like that. Instead use a class as suggested by @freedomn-m

Comment: *Assuming* your `returnColor` gets the css value of the cell, each browser may return it differently, eg with/without a space, maybe as an `argb` or even using the colour name "lightgrey" or similar.   It's not guaranteed to return in a specific format.   Of course, we have no idea what `returnColor` actually does, maybe it *does* look for a class and then return a hardcoded string.... who knows? (well I *guess* OP does, but that's only a guess).

Comment: @freedomn-m can you help me with a refrence how should I make that happen?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to provide a solution.  If you could create a [mcve] in a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) then a solution could easily be provided.   To hazard some assumptions:  where you "set its colour" instead of `style=color:red` use `class="active"` then your "checkBottom" would be a one liner `return $("tr.active").last()`.  I suggest you ask a new question along the lines of "how do I use classes to find the last row" and include some html.   Changing *this* question to that would be too much of a change from comparing strings with/without space.

Comment: To fix *this* question, change your `returnColor` from `return color;` to `return color.replace(/\s/g, '');` - adjust for whatever is in returnColor of course - then compare without spaces.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  The behaviour of the `===` test in javaScript is well-documented, and it is reasonable of people to expect you to give it a read before you ask for their help.  In future, please make sure you read the relevant documentation before posting a question.  If you still have a question after you've read the docs please post a question that includes a note about the research you've done.  For details about how much research is expected, please see this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score -1):

If you're some kind of space-ist who hates spaces, you can ignore them like this:

```js
if(colorReport.replace(/\s/g, '') ==='rgb(128,      128,    128)'.replace(/\s/g, '')){
 //...
}
```

This uses the string's [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove all whitespace.

You can make a function out of it, if you need to:

```
function compareStrings(str1, str2){
   return str1.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase() === str2.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()
}

if(compareStrings(colorReport, 'rgb(128, 128, 128)')){
   // ...
}
```

Comment: @Andreas - If you can show me the rule that says humor is not allowed in answers I will happily remove it. Counter-question: How is complaining about it productive?

Comment: @Andreas - BTW, Have you seen [Bobince's famous regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1444609)? It's pretty funny.